# ViewController is getting called multiple times from my rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, pushviewcontroller

I am little confused about `UINavigationController` stack. 
I am showing my `UIViewController("SubmitRequestViewController")` from my `rootViewController("ViewController")`.

Below is my code:

```
let controller = SubmitRequestViewController.init(nibName: "SubmitRequestViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Now I am just trying to come back from `SubmitRequestViewController` to my `rootViewController`.

```
//Home Button
@objc fileprivate func backHome() {
    let _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}

//Back Button
@objc fileprivate func backButton() {
    let _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

If I go again to my "`SubmitRequestViewController`" its getting call twice.

So this is going continuously. It will call multiple times if I will repeat the above steps.

Now what I got is :-

`navigationController.viewControllers.count` is getting increased continuesly.

I am trying to pop to `navigationController` but still it's present.

I tried this also :-

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Actually I am firing a notification in my DrawerViewController class :-

```
//Submit Request
else if itemArray[indexPath.row].contains("SUBMIT REQUEST") == true {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue : AssessNowKyes.submitRequest), object: nil)
}
```

I am calling it in my ViewControllerClass :-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(submitRequestClicked), name: Notification.Name(rawValue : AssessNowKyes.submitRequest), object: nil)
}

//Submit Request Clicked
@objc fileprivate func submitRequestClicked() {
    let controller = SubmitRequestViewController.init(nibName: "SubmitRequestViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

I am doing it. I don't know about I have to removeObserver also? Because I tried that also. It's not working.

Comment: can you try to run the popviewcontroller method on main thread?

Comment: remove let _ = , self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) is what needed

Comment: U mean only this self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) ?

Comment: I tried @Basheer. But same problem.  

DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }

Comment: maybe u can check the deinit in SubmitRequestViewController.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reappear this issue.

I guess you must fire push action twice.

- add breakpoint on `viewDidLoad` on `SubmitRequestViewController` to check if `viewDidLoad` was called twice
- check if you fire it on storyboard and programming again
- remove nib and create again to check if this is a bug of Xcode

Comment: Ok I will try this once. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check where you are calling it. Are you calling it in `ViewWillAppear`?

If yes, this this wrong.

```
let controller = SubmitRequestViewController.init(nibName: "SubmitRequestViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: You mean I am writing it in ViewWillAppear ?

Comment: yes I mean that or any function that fire  when you present this rootController

Comment: Actually what I am doing is I am firing notification . I will close my drawer and I will fire a notification and calling that.

Comment: where is you fire this notification  just share it

Comment: Yeah I will share. 
Thanks

Comment: @kishor0011 Maybe the problem is with multiple times adding the notificationlistener.  (or not removing it properly on deinit)  The steps you showed above should give you the desired result.  Also check the deinit is called when expected.

Comment: @CarienvanZyl I edited my question.
Please tell me ?

Comment: I am adding once only notificationlistener as you can see in my code above.
Where I have to remove or deinit it? Thanks